# Rails - How to pass data between Rails controller and JavaScript Stimulus controller to dynamically change view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I have a Rails app where I have a search results page, which pulls results based on a user's input from a form.

To simplify the Rails controller method:

```
def search_results
  # [...] ActiveRecord queries to get results
  @movies.shuffle!
end
```

Then in the view, I only want to display the first three results.  At the moment, that's something like:

```
<%@movies[0..2].each do |movie|%>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center" data-controller="search-result-card">
    <%# Visual of the card %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

What I want to do is have a refresh button on this page replaces the visible cards with the next three @movies, but without actually reloading the page.

I've drawn up a refresh button and I've got a data-controller on it... but I'm just not sure how I can use this to change the code.

```
<div class="refresh-button" data-controller="refresh">
  <button data-action="click->refresh#next">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

I'm not sure whether I need to create a partial of the card... or if there's a way to simply change the imbedded Ruby so that `<%@movies[0..2].each do |movie|%>` becomes `<%@movies[3..5].each do |movie|%>` and have the view update accordingly.

I don't think that rendering and then hiding all of the results would be feasible, because there could be tens of thousands of them potentially (although I could be wrong and this might be fine to do).

Any suggestions most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like plain old pagination.

If there could be *thousands* of movies you'd be generation markup/html for thousands of movies. With pagination you'd get get 3 records at a time. Could even use a turbo-frame to replace the next 3.

But if you really want to do what your thinking, you'd have hide all cards except for the first 3, then use stimulus to get the next or last three cards.

A test example

**Controller**

```rb
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = Array.new(100) { |e| e = e + 1 }
  end
```

**Template using slim**

```rb
.bg-white
  div[data-controller="movies"]
    - cnt = 0
    button.btn[data-action="click->movies#last_set"] Last
    button.btn[data-action="click->movies#next_set"] Next
    - @movies.each do |m|
      - if cnt < 3
        div[data-movies-target="movie" class='block'] = "This is movie #{m}"
        - cnt += 1
      - else
        div[data-movies-target="movie" class='hidden'] = "This is movie #{m}"
```

**Stimulus Controller**

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="movies"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['movie']

  connect() {
    this.size = this.movieTargets.length
    this.idx = 0
    // this.idx points to the first current cards (3 for example)
  }

  next_set() {
    let curr = this.idx
    this.idx = curr + 3 // set new idx
    if (this.idx > this.size) {this.idx = this.size - 3}
    for (var i = curr; i <= curr + 2; i++) {
      this.movieTargets[i].classList.add("hidden")
    }
    for (var i = this.idx; i <= this.idx + 2; i++) {
      this.movieTargets[i].classList.remove("hidden")
    }
    // console.log(`idx = ${this.idx}`)
  }

  last_set() {
    let curr = this.idx
    this.idx = curr - 3 // set new idx
    if (this.idx < 0 ) {this.idx = 0}
    for (var i = curr; i <= curr + 2; i++) {
      this.movieTargets[i].classList.add("hidden")
    }
    for (var i = this.idx; i <= this.idx + 2; i++) {
      this.movieTargets[i].classList.remove("hidden")
    }
    // console.log(`idx = ${this.idx}`)
  }

}
```

Just a rough example.

EDIT  Not very good at javascript and cleaned up the stimulus controller, added variable number of elements to display and work with pages instead of elements.

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['perPage','movie','status','nextBtn','lastBtn']

  connect() {
    this.size = this.movieTargets.length
    this.page = 0
    this.perPage = Number(this.perPageTarget.innerHTML)
    this.pages = Math.floor(this.size/this.perPage)
    if ((this.size % this.perPage) > 0) {this.pages += 1}
    this.setStatus()
    // this.page points to the current set of cards (3 for example)
  }


  next_set() {
    if (this.page == (this.pages - 1)) {return}
    this.hide()
    this.page += 1
    this.show()
    this.setStatus()
  }

  last_set() {
    if (this.page == 0) {return}
    this.hide()
    this.page -= 1
    this.show()
    this.setStatus()
  }

  hide(){
    let curr = this.page * this.perPage
    let last = curr + this.perPage - 1
    while(curr <= last){
      if (curr >= 0 && curr < this.size) {
        this.movieTargets[curr].classList.add("hidden")
      }
      curr++
    }
  }

  show(){
    let curr = this.page * this.perPage
    let last = curr + this.perPage - 1
    while(curr <= last){
      if (curr >= 0 && curr < this.size) {
        this.movieTargets[curr].classList.remove("hidden")
      }
      curr++
    }
  }

  setStatus(){
    this.statusTarget.innerHTML = `Page ${this.page + 1} of ${this.pages}`
    if (this.page == 0) {
      this.lastBtnTarget.classList.add('hidden')
    }else{
      this.lastBtnTarget.classList.remove('hidden')
    }
    if (this.page == this.pages) {
      this.nextBtnTarget.classList.add('hidden')
    }else{
      this.nextBtnTarget.classList.remove('hidden')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this (sorry I didn't seem to get an email to notify me of the answer).  I've essentially implemented this, and it does what I want.  I've put a hard limit on the number of results that I get back, so the page is never generating more than 100 cards, and I've worked the Javascript so that it doesn't attempt to load up imbedded video content until the card is made visible in the view.  Cheers!!

Comment: My javascript was kinda of a kludge. I added a cleaned up the version, but you've already implemented something.  Good luck